# MySql getting sum: one table contains values, in other tables is rest of data

Tags: php, mysql

i have three tables.

- First table(items) has: item_id, item_name, and item_value.
- Second table(handouts) contains: handout_id, handout_item_id, month, 
  vol_id, receiver_name.
- Third table(volunteer) contains volunteer_id, volunteer_name

I need to output monthly sum of items value, per volunteer for the selected month.
Here is what i have so far(what i am stuck with :-s):

```
    function mesec_svi(){
global $konekcija;
$mes=$_GET['mes'];

$query= "SELECT DISTINCT vol_id FROM handouts WHERE mes = {$mes} ";
$mesec_svi = mysqli_query($konekcija, $query);
 potvrda_query($mesec_svi);

 while($mesec_svi_lista=mysqli_fetch_assoc($mesec_svi)){

 $volid= $mesec_svi_lista["vol_id"];     

 echo $volid.' ';   

 $query1= "SELECT handout_item_id FROM handouts WHERE vol_id =  {$volid}     AND  mes = {$mes}";     
   $mesec_svi_o = mysqli_query($konekcija, $query1);
    potvrda_query($mesec_svi_o);
 while($mesec_svi_olista=mysqli_fetch_assoc($mesec_svi_o)){
  $itemid= $mesec_svi_olista["handout_item_id"];

 $query2= "SELECT item_value FROM items WHERE itemid = {$itemid}";

  $pr_svi_o = mysqli_query($konekcija, $query2);
    potvrda_query($pr_svi_o);



while($pr_svi_olista=mysqli_fetch_assoc($pr_svi_o)){
        $pr= $pr_svi_olista["item_value"];
        echo '</br>'.$pr.'</br>';} 

 }

     }
 }
```

This is displaying results:

```
1 
200
100
50
2
50
50
100
```

Where 1 and 2 are volunteer ids and other numbers are items value. I need those values summed.

```
1
350
2
200
```

I tried sum() and array_sum but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `INNER JOIN`. The query would be -

```
SELECT sum(item_value) as sum_item FROM handouts 
INNER JOIN items ON items.itemid = handouts.handout_item_id
WHERE vol_id = {$volid} AND  mes = {$mes} GROUP BY items.itemid
```

And loop through it -

```
while($mesec_svi_olista=mysqli_fetch_assoc($mesec_svi_o)){
    echo $mesec_svi_olista['sum_item'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: i am not getting any sum output, I dont understand this part of query  `as sum_item FROM handouts`. i dont have sum_item column.